# MYSQL: how can I get the day of week, month of year from date whose datatype is char(10)

Tags: mysql, date

The datatype of date column in my table is char(10). So each date is stored as a string like '02/01/2016/'.

How can I get the day of week and month of year from this '02/01/2016' in mysql?

Comment: By day of week do you mean e.g. Wednesday?  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but your schema is seriously broken if you're storing dates as character data. You would probably be better off fixing *that* abomination than trying all sorts of SQL gymnastics to work around it :-)

Comment: could be easy if you use date/datetime

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string to `DATE` datatype using `STR_TO_DATE` function, and then use `DATE_FORMAT` function.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( '02/01/2016', '%m/%d/%Y'), '%w') AS dow
     , DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( '02/01/2016', '%m/%d/%Y'), '%c') AS moy
```

(The format specifier needs to match the format of the string. This demonstration assumes that the string is in month/day/year format, that this represents February 1st, and not January 2nd.)

If you want to return a string like 'Monday', use `'%W'` in place of `'%w'`

---

MySQL Reference Manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 0):

As @paxdiablo commented, you should *seriously* consider storing your date information as `date`, `datetime`, or `timestamp`.  That being said, if you must live with your current setup, you can work around this by first parsing your text into a date using [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and then extracting out a string weekday and month name using [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).  Something like this should work:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%W') AS day_of_week,
       DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%M') AS month_of_year
FROM yourTable
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle